# .htaccess multiple parameters in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm now using this `.htaccess` file. It only changes the URL from `www.example.com/?page=home` to `www.example.com/home`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I want to add more `$_GET` parameter, for example `www.example.com/home/parameter1/value1/`.
and preferably that you can do those parameters indefinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this "indefinitely" using `.htaccess` alone. You would need to decide on the *maximum* number (N) of parameters and write a directive for each in order: N, N-1, N-2, ... 1. However, you are also limited by the number of backreferences that are supported. ie. With just `$1` to `$9`, you are limited to 4 parameters, using your method of including the *parameter name* in the URL path as well.

For example:

```
# 3 additional parameters
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [L]

# 2 additional parameters
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [L]

# 1 additional parameter
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&$2=$3 [L]

# No parameters (just the page)
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

These all allow an optional trailing slash (as in your current example). However, you are better off deciding whether a trailing slash is required or not and choosing one or the other. Having the trailing slash optional simply promotes *duplicate content*.

This URL *pattern* is also a bit too "generalised" in my opinion. It is more usual to be specific and avoid including the parameter *name* in the URL. For example: `example.com/home/value1/value2/value2` - the parameter names (`param1`, `param2`, etc.) would be hardcoded in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. This would also allow you to have twice as many *parameters*.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
> ```

You shouldn't need two directives here. (Providing the `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly.)